# Install local timestamp server for ClickOnce signing

Tags: timestamp, certificate, clickonce

In our company we use signed ClickOnce applications that we develop ourselves. On the Signing page, there is an option to define a timestamp server, and it works when we use a URL from the internet like "http://timestamp.digicert.com".

But some of our pcs do not have internet access, so I want to try to use a timestamp server on our own network instead.
How do I install such a server? 
I have been unable to find this information anywhere, including in the documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-sign-application-and-deployment-manifests?view=vs-2017

I found this tool under OpenSSL:
https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man1/ts.html

However, the page says; "There is no support for sending the requests/responses automatically over HTTP or TCP yet as suggested in RFC 3161. The users must send the requests either by ftp or e-mail."

I think I will need HTTP for it to work.

I also found these commercial products:

https://www.signfiles.com/timestamping/
https://www.ascertia.com/products/adss-tsa-server/